# Example of a set $A$ such that $\lambda(\partial A^\delta)>0$?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A\subset \mathbb R^n$ be a compact set, and denote by $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$. Given $\delta>0$ define $$A^\delta := \{x\in\mathbb R^n; |x-a|<\delta\ \text{for some }a\in A\}.$$

> **Question:** Is it possible to find $A$ such that $\lambda(\partial A^\delta) >0$ for every $\delta>0$ small enough?

I believe the above question is false because $A^\delta$ seems to "regularize" the boundary of $A$. However, I could not prove it. Does anyone have any ideas/references?

Comment: I think the boundaries are disjoint for different $\delta$'s, so we can have $\lambda(\partial A^\delta) >0$ only for countably many $\delta$'s.

Comment: This is a great observation!